# String to retrieve that im omitting using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, logic

I need to fetch the  `img` tag info as well (`<img src="images/construction.jpg" border="0" alt="" />`) what function and code amendment i need to do as this code im using is in my `foreach` loop as the data is iterating from the db.

My working Code---

```
<?php

$content = '<p><img src="images/construction.jpg" border="0" alt="" />This is only a testing phase data</p>';

$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);

echo $content;  //OUTPUT --  This is only a testing phase data

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`preg_match`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to retreive that data instead of [`preg_replace`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).